# httpd Virtual Hosts File Redirecting to Incorrect Website

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, virtualhost

I have an EC2 server running Amazon Linux AMI.

I have a number of websites running on the server and have an httpd-vhosts.conf file setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/vol2/html-studio/www"
ServerName "studioofcrayons.com"
ErrorLog "logs/studioofcrayons.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/studioofcrayons.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/vol2/html-studio/www"
ServerName "www.studioofcrayons.com"
ErrorLog "logs/studioofcrayons.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/studioofcrayons.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This site works correctly, as do the others I have setup.

Recently though I have added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/vol2/html-snr/www"
ServerName "sundaynightraving.com"
ErrorLog "logs/sundaynightraving.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/sundaynightraving.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/vol2/html-snr/www"
ServerName "www.sundaynightraving.com"
ErrorLog "logs/sundaynightraving.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/sundaynightraving.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

[www.sundaynightraving.com](http://www.sundaynightraving.com) works, but for some reason going to sundaynightraving.com redirects to the studioofcrayons.com website and URL instead.

I cannot see anything in the logfiles, there doesn't appear to be any errors being generated.
httpd -t returns 'syntax ok'
httpd -S returns

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server studioofcrayons.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost studioofcrayons.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.studioofcrayons.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:9)
         port 80 namevhost sofc.uk (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:17)
         port 80 namevhost www.sofc.uk (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:25)
         port 80 namevhost oneillmtc.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:33)
         port 80 namevhost www.oneillmtc.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:41)
         port 80 namevhost datasaab.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:49)
         port 80 namevhost www.datasaab.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:57)
         port 80 namevhost sundaynightraving.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:65)
         port 80 namevhost www.sundaynightraving.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:73)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/vol2"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Is there something I have missed, or something else I can check?
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Does it do a redirect or it just serves the studioofcrayons.com content when you load up sundaynightraving.com?

Comment: It redirects to the studioofcrayons.com website and url.
Edited question to clarify this.

Comment: If you remove the sundaynightraving.com virtual host and add in
 www.sundaynightraving.com the following entry without quotes "ServerAlias studioofcrayons.com" does the error persists? Would be possible to you to use server alias instead of creating multiple virtual hosts for the same main domains?

Comment: Also, just as an tought, its possible that you might have a host entrie that redirects in your machine? When I tried to access sundaynightraving.com it did not redirected me to any other page.

Comment: I've removed the vhost for sundaynightraving.com and I have tried adding separately,
ServerAlias sundaynightraving.com
ServerAlias "sundaynightraving.com"
ServerAlias studioofcrayons.com
ServerAlias "studioofcrayons.com"

Each time I restarted httpd and each time sundaynigthraving.com still redirects studioofcrayons.com and loads that the website for studioofcrayons.com, not sundaynightraving.com

Comment: I've tried a different computer and on a different internet connection (mobile not broadband) and it still redirects.

Comment: You shouldn't have a redirect with this code, do you have some .htaccess files that have some rewrite rules?

Comment: It appears to have resolved itself overnight and using ServerAlias, sundaynightraving.com now redirects to www.sundaynightraving.com as I'd expect.
Perhaps it was an issue with a DNS somewhere?

Anyway, all fixed now, thank you to everyone who inputted on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had now appears to have resolved itself overnight.